# Mongodb Typescript UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'conn' of undefined at Object.connectToDatabase [as default]

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

typescript connection to mongo database throws error , it can read conn of undefined after conn has been declared globally

**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'conn' of undefined
at Object.connectToDatabase [as default]**

```
import { MongoClient, Db } from "mongodb";
import config from "../config/config";
const { dbName, mongoDBUri } = config;

type MongoConnection = {
  client: MongoClient;
  db: Db;
};

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      mongodb: {
        conn: MongoConnection | null;
        promise: Promise<MongoConnection> | null;
      };
    }
  }
}
let cached = global.mongodb;
async function connectToDatabase() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn;
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    };

    cached.promise = MongoClient.connect(mongoDBUri as string, opts).then(
      (client) => {
        return {
          client,
          db: client.db(dbName),
        };
      }
    );
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise;
  return cached.conn;
}

export default connectToDatabase;
```

Comment: Clearly, `global.mongodb` is undefined. You'll have to assign a value to it somewhere.

Comment: please where and how can I add the value to `global.mongodb`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below setup

```
//interfaces/db.interface
export interface dbConfig {
    host: string;
    port: number;
    database: string;
    username: string;
    password: string;
}

//database.ts
import { dbConfig } from "@interfaces/db.interface";

const { host, port, database, username, password }: dbConfig = config.get("dbConfig");

export const dbConnection = {
    url: `mongodb://${username}:${password}@${host}:${port}/${database}?authSource=admin`,
    options: {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useCreateIndex: true
    },
};


//app.ts (express app)
import { dbConnection } from "@databases";
constructor(routes: Routes[]) {
    this.app = express();
    this.port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    this.env  = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
    this.connectToDatabase();
}
private connectToDatabase() {
    if (this.env !== "production") {
        set("debug", true);
    }
    connect(dbConnection.url, dbConnection.options)
    .catch((error) =>
        console.log(`${error}`)
    );
}
```

Here I am assuming you have the setup of paths in the tsconfig.json file so that @ will work in imports.

Answer (score 0):

After several times of trying, I had to use the NextJs MongoDB connection pattern and convert it to typescript and it worked perfectly fine

```
import config from "./../config/config";
import { MongoClient, Db } from "mongodb";

const { dbName, mongoDBUri } = config;

if (!mongoDBUri) {
  throw new Error(
    "Define the mongoDBUri environment variable inside .env"
  );
}

if (!dbName) {
  throw new Error(
    "Define the dbName environment variable inside .env"
  );
}

type MongoConnection = {
  client: MongoClient;
  db: Db;
};

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      mongodb: {
        conn: MongoConnection | null;
        promise: Promise<MongoConnection> | null;
      };
    }
  }
}
let cached = global.mongodb;
if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongodb = { conn: null, promise: null };
}
export default async function connectToDatabase() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn;
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    console.log("Establishing new database connection");
    const opts = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    };

    cached.promise = MongoClient.connect(mongoDBUri as string, opts).then(
      (client) => {
        return {
          client,
          db: client.db(dbName),
        };
      }
    );
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise;
  return cached.conn;
}
```